# Is this operation thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

In the following example when the "Submit" button is clicked the value of the static variable Count is incremented. But is this operation thread safe? Is using Appliation object the proper way of doing such operation? The questions are applicable to Web form application s as well.

The count always seem to increase as I click the Submit button.

View(Razor):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>

<body>
    <form>
        <p>@ViewBag.BeforeCount</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.BeforeCount = StaticVariableTester.Count;
        StaticVariableTester.Count += 50;
        return View();
    }     
}
```

Static Class:

```
public class StaticVariableTester
{
    public static int Count;
}
```

Comment: Short answer : **no**

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37976/Writing-Thread-Safe-Code-in-C

Comment: No.Please read these questions:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254750/i-need-to-create-a-thread-safe-static-variable-in-c-sharp-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941181/are-static-variables-thread-safe-c-sharp


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907612/mspec-how-to-make-static-variables-thread-safe

Comment: `Static` variables are not thread safe.

Comment: Static variables to increment items are rarely a good way to do things in a web based situation. What are you trying to do.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Ridiculous statement! Amusing by the way

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel Are they?

Comment: `Static` and thread safety are orthogonal, please read about thread safety.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel A link would be helpful

Comment: @Bharadwaj My favourites [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx) and [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Thread_Safety). They are not enough google will give you more :)

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel Thanks :) "A programmer is always a learner". :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not. The += operator is done in 3 steps: read the value of the variable, increase it by one, assign the new value. Expanded:

```
var count = StaticVariableTester.Count;
count = count + 50;
StaticVariableTester.Count = count;
```

A thread could be preempted between any two of these steps. This means that if `Count` is 0, and two threads execute `+= 50` concurrently, it's possible `Count` will be 50 instead of 100.

1. `T1` reads `Count` as 0.
2. `T2` reads `Count` as 0
3. `T1` adds 0 + 50
4. `T2` adds 0 + 50
5. `T1` assigns 50 to `Count`
6. `T2` assigns 50 to `Count`
7. `Count` equals 50

Additionally, it could also be preempted between your first two instructions. Which means two concurrent threads might *both* set `ViewBag.BeforeCount` to 0, and only *then* increment `StaticVariableTester.Count`.

Use a lock

```
private readonly object _countLock = new object();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    lock(_countLock)
    {
        ViewBag.BeforeCount = StaticVariableTester.Count;
        StaticVariableTester.Count += 50;
    }
    return View();
}
```

Or use `Interlocked.Add`

```
public static class StaticVariableTester
{
    private static int _count;

    public static int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
    }

    public static int IncrementCount(int value)
    {
        //increments and returns the old value of _count
        return Interlocked.Add(ref _count, value) - value;
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.BeforeCount = StaticVariableTester.IncrementCount(50);
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Increment is not atomic so is not thread safe.

Check out [`Interlocked.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33821kfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Adds two 32-bit integers and replaces the first integer with the sum, as an atomic operation.

You'd use it like this:

```
Interlocked.Add(ref StaticVariableTester.Count, 50);
```

---

Personally I'd wrap this in your `StaticVariableTester` class:

```
public class StaticVariableTester
{
    private static int count;

    public static void Add(int i)
    {
        Interlocked.Add(ref count, i);
    }

    public static int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
    }
}
```

---

If you want the returned values (as per dcastro's comment) then you could always do:

```
public static int AddAndGetNew(int i)
{
     return Interlocked.Add(ref count, i);
}

public static int AddAndGetOld(int i)
{
     return Interlocked.Add(ref count, i) - i;
}
```

In your code you could do

```
ViewBag.BeforeCount = StaticVariableTester.AddAndGetOld(50);
```

Comment: Probably want `Interlocked.Add`

Comment: What this does? He adds 50! not just `var++`

Comment: In addition to not being thread-safe, it won't work across servers in the case of a web farm.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yep. Updated.

Comment: That won't work if `Count` is a property, which it should be.

Comment: That's still not thread-safe, a thread could be preempted between reading `Count` into `ViewBag.BeforeCount` and incrementing `Count`.

Comment: @dcastro The question as I understood it was whether the increment was thread safe, not the read as well.

Comment: @dav_i I'm pretty sure the OP didn't realize that there's more to thread-safety here than the increment.

Comment: @dcastro Yeah fair enough about the OP. MSDN says the return value is "The new value stored at *location1*."

Comment: @dav_i You're right, I was mistaken on that ;) I retracted that bit of my comment. I was under the impression `Add` worked like `CompareExchange`, which does return the old value.

Comment: @dcastro Now it looks like I'm just going mad! :P

Answer (score 4):

If a method (instance or static) only references variables scoped within that method then it is thread safe because each thread has its own stack. You also can achieve thread safety by using any variety of synchronization mechanisms.

This operation is not thread safe because it uses shared variable: ViewBag.BeforeCount.

[What Makes a Method Thread-safe? What are the rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848067/what-makes-a-method-thread-safe-what-are-the-rules)

Comment: This answer implies an *if and only if* relationship between use of non-local variables and thread safety. However, it is entirely possible to have thread-safe code which references externally scoped variables, through any variety of synchronization mechanisms.